# Read lines in Rust with match result

Tags: rust, error-handling, io

I'm pretty new with Rust and trying to implement some basic stuff.
So one of the samples from the doc is about reading lines from a text file: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/file/read_lines.html

The sample code works (obviously...) but I wanted to modify it to add some error handling but the compiler complains about the result I define

```
// the result after -> is not valid...
pub fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> std::result::Result<std::io::Lines<std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>>, std::io::Error>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename);
    let file = match file {
        Ok(file) => io::BufReader::new(file).lines(),
        Err(error) => panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", error),
    };
}

// this is fine
pub fn read_lines2<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

I've tried different suggestions from the intellisense but no luck.

Any idea about how to define the result when there is an `Ok/Err` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the intent of your code correctly, here is a more canonical version:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*};
use std::path::Path;

pub fn read_lines(filename: &Path) -> io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>> {
    let file = File::open(filename).expect("Problem opening the file");
    io::BufReader::new(file).lines()
}
```

If you want the caller to handle any errors, return something like `io::Result<T>` (an alias for `std::result::Result<T, io::Error>`), indicating a possible failure. However, if you decide to handle the error inside the function using something like `panic!()` or `Result::expect()`, then there is no need to return a `Result` to the caller since the function only returns to the caller if no error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
pub fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> std::result::Result<std::io::Lines<std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>>, std::io::Error>
where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename);
    match file {
        Ok(file) => Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines()),
        Err(error) => panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", error),
    }
}
```

I removed the `let file =` and `;` to enable implicit return, and added an `Ok()` wrapper around the happy path.